# Second toc is empty

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to finalize a document wich has annexes.
So for the first document, the TOC is correct, but the TOC of the second document (wich will be included at the end of the first one )is empty as shown in the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\tableofcontents
\section{Document 1} % (fold)
\label{sec:document_1}
\section{Document 1} % (fold)
\label{sec:document_2}
\subsection{Subsection document 1} % (fold)
\label{sub:subsection_document_1}
a
   \tableofcontents
   %========HERE THE TOC OF THE SECOND DOC SHOULD APPEAR and from here this will be the content of the second doc
   \section{Document 2.1} % (fold)
   \label{sec:document_2_1}
    \subsection{Subsection document 2}
    \section{Document 2.2} %

\end{document}
```

[image]
I forgot to say, that the second TOC, should contain only the element of document 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would add parts, the minitoc package could be used to show toc for each part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{minitoc}%

\doparttoc% Prepare minitoc package for part tocs usage

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\faketableofcontents

\part{Document 1}
\parttoc
\section{Document 1} % (fold)
\label{sec:document_1}
\section{Document 1} % (fold)
\label{sec:document_2}
\subsection{Subsection document 1} % (fold)
\label{sub:subsection_document_1}
a
  \part{Document 2}
  \parttoc
   %========HERE THE TOC OF THE SECOND DOC SHOULD APPEAR and from here this will be the content of the second doc
   \section{Document 2.1} % (fold)
   \label{sec:document_2_1}
    \subsection{Subsection document 2}
    \section{Document 2.2} %

\end{document}
```